# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml

Tags: ajax, web-services

In VS 2010 i have two projects,one for webservice and another for asp.net pages.

i try to call a webservice (from the .js of an asp.net page) like this:

```
var host =  "localhost:15932";

var url = "http://" + host + "/MyWebService.asmx/GetFeed?callback=?";


$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'Get',
    url: url,
    data:{ CountryId: CountryId, FeedDateString: FeedDateString, Previous: Previous},
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     //contentType:'text/xml ',
    processData: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',

    success: function (response) {
        var result= response.d;
    ,
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
        ,
    failure: function (msg) {
        alert('somethin went wrong' + msg);
    }
});
```

the call goes wel ,but the result returned from the webservice is xml ,and chrome shows an error message:"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml"
i get an xml stream when i type this in my browser:

"http://localhost:15932/MyWebService.asmx/GetCountryFeed?callback=jsonp1339760946308&CountryId=1&FeedDateString=&Previous=true"

the code of my webservice method:

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Get feed")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json,UseHttpGet=true)]
    public List<Feed> GetFeed(int CountryId, string FeedDateString, bool Previous)
    {

        return (new UserFeedManager()).GetFeed(CountryId, FeeDate, Previous);
    }
```

what to change to make the response.d in json format?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the web services response.

1. Set GetFeed's return type to void.
2. Serialize List.
3. Return the json:
           HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json)
           HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

You may want to create a class to handle your response's and pass in your functions that return json with a Func function or Func parameter.